# How to use a union in a struct, and typedef each struct with different union type?

Tags: c

I want to create a linked list, but I want the data field to be either int or float. I wrote some code like the following:

```
union int_or_float
{
    int int_member;
    float float_member;
};

struct node 
{
    union int_or_float data;
    struct node *next;
};
```

I want to write stuff like:

```
typedef struct node item;
```

but how to specify which type in union do I like item to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's done automatically when you access the data. A union is nothing more than a slightly-less-kludgy way of casting a pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

union number {
  int i;
  float f;
};

struct node {
  union number data;
  struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node item;

int main(void) {
  item myItem;

  myItem.data.i = 12; /* Now contains an int */
  myItem.data.f = 12.0; /* Now contains a float */
  printf("location of myItem.data is %p\n", &myItem.data);
  printf("location of myItem.data.f is %p\n", &myItem.data.f);  
  printf("myItem.data is %f\n", *(float *)(&myItem.data));
  printf("myItem.data.f is %f\n", myItem.data.f);
  printf("sizeof(myItem.data) is %lu\n", sizeof(*(float *)(&myItem.data)));
  printf("sizeof(myItem.data.f) is %lu\n", sizeof(myItem.data.f));

  return 0;
}
```

This will output

```
location of myItem.data is 0x7fff5fbff9f0
location of myItem.data.f is 0x7fff5fbff9f0
myItem.data is 12.000000
myItem.data.f is 12.000000
sizeof(myItem.data) is 4
sizeof(myItem.data.f) is 4
```

run/tested on an Intel Mac with gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5659)

Comment: but how do I dynamically allocate memory for an item? like item *new_node = (item*)malloc(sizeof(item)); how can it determine how much memory should it get? 8bit or 16 bit?

Comment: The union is the size of its largest member. item *new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));

Comment: omg, thanks, guess I should not use union here then. I just want the linked list structure can apply to a lot of types, like hold either a char or a char*, but apparently it's too much waste of a memory.. thank you so much though!

Comment: Not really, that's an incredibly small amount of memory to worry about. Honestly, your structures would increase more in size just from moving to a 64-bit architecture (so struct node *next would be a 64-bit pointer instead of a 32-bit pointer) than it would from the minor difference from an int to a float. You'll notice in my example that the float is 4 bytes in size -- which is identical to the size of an integer on my system.

Answer (score 3):

You don't. The fundamental thing about unions is that it can be whatever data you put into it.

If you write to `int_member`, then it'll hold an int.

If you write to `float_member`, it'll hold a float. (And if you subsequently read from `int_member` all hell breaks loose.)

Comment: Hey, help me discourage nasal demons here!

Comment: There's undefined behaviour and other sorts of undefined behaviour (UB). They can all trigger nasal demons, but some are more likely to do so than others. Thomas is absolutely correct; the C standard says that if you store to the float member and then read from the int member, you incur UB, and anything could happen including demons flying out of your nose (nasal demons) or reformatting your disk, or ... Fortunately, this seldom happens; hence my comment 'Hell might break loose, but...'. Other types of UB are more likely to lead to major problems. You would be wise to avoid all UB.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to "specify" anything. You just store the value in the appropriate member of the union.

However, it appears that your structs are intended to serve as nodes in some list. If your list is intended to contain different types of values simultaneously, then of course you need some way to determine what type each element of the list currently holds. This can only be done manually. I.e. it is your responsibility to store that information inside each list item somehow. For example, you can add a `type` field to your struct

```
struct node 
{
    enum { INT, FLOAT } type;
    union int_or_float data;
    struct node *next;
};

...

struct node *p;

p = malloc(sizeof *p);
p->type = INT;
p->data.i = 42;
/* ... and add it to the list */

p = malloc(sizeof *p);
p->type = FLOAT;
p->data.f = 3.14;
/* ... and add it to the list */
```

Comment: but how do I dynamically allocate memory for an item? like item new_node = (item)malloc(sizeof(item)); how can it determine how much memory should it get? 8bit or 16 bit?

Comment: You simply use the size of the struct. It already has enough space for the larger of the two types.

Answer (score 1):

By the time you add extra storage and conditionals to check whether the union is storing an `int` or a `float`, you could have just changed the field to `double` and then you could easily fit any value that would fit in either `int` or `float` without having to worry about which type it is (on most implementations where `int` is 32-bit and `double` is IEEE 754 double precision). I think this would be a much cleaner design...

Comment: +1 for the out of box observation, which is certainly cleaner for the case of `int` paired with `float`. However it won't generalize well to additional types for the data.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

union int_or_float
{
    int int_member;
    float float_member;
};

struct node 
{
    union int_or_float data;
    struct node *next;
};

int main()
{

    typedef struct node item;

    item one;
    one.data.int_member = 10;

    item two;
    two.data.float_member = 10.f;

    printf("%d", one.data.int_member);
    printf("%f", two.data.float_member);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field to the struct indicating which union member is currently valid.  A simple example:

```
union int_or_float
{
    int int_member;
    float float_member;
};

struct node 
{
    union int_or_float data;
    bool int_is_valid;
    struct node *next;
};
```

(This assumes you have `#include <stdbool.h>`.)

Note that it's entirely up to you to keep the value of the `int_is_valid` member consistent with the last value you stored, and to retrieve `int_member` only if `int_is_valid` is true, and retrieve `float_member` only if `int_is_valid` is false.

In practice, it would be clearer to use an `enum` rather than a `bool`.

Answer (score -1):

you might be better off storing both a float and a int, then use a assignment functions to set both to their correct values.  a class might work better for this

```
struct node 
{
    int idata;
    float fdata;
    struct node *next;
    void setData(int data);  
    void setData(float data);
};

node::setData(int data)
{
    idata = data;
    fdata = (float)data;
}

node::setData(float data)
{
    idata = (int)data;
    fdata = data;
}
```